# Can I install 14.04 over pre-installed 12.04 desktop?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, system-installation

Can I install 14.04 over pre-installed 12.04 desktop on an ASUS X200CA notebook PC? And will the new version 14.04 replace the 12.04 version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

During the installation you will be prompted what to do; one of the options is to -replace- the current operating system (in your case 12.04). This will erase everything and have you start from scratch.

Whatever you do: make sure your personal files are on a backup and make sure you can view the backup.

Example image with 11.10 going to 12.04:

[image]